# Reduction of order of differential equation!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that y=x is a solution to the following differential equation

$$(x^2-x+1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(x^2+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+(x+1)y=0$$

Find a linearly independent solution to the new differential equation by reducing the order. Write a general solution.

I am stuck somewhere here.

My work is below!

Suppose that $f(x)=x$ is a non trivial solution to the differential equation then by the transformation $y=vx$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2\frac{dv}{dx}+x\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}$$

$$ (x^2-x+1)(2\frac{dv}{dx}+x\frac{d^2v}{dx^2})-(x^2+x)(v+x\frac{dv}{dx})+(x+1)(vx)=0$$

$$ 2((x^2-x+1))\frac{dv}{dx}+x((x^2-x+1))\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}-(x^2+x)(x)\frac{dv}{dx})=0$$

$$x((x^2-x+1))\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}+(-x^3+x^2-2x+2)\frac{dv}{dx}=0 $$

By letting $$w=\frac{dv}{dx}$$ ,$$\frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}$$

$$x(x^2-x+1))\frac{dw}{dx}+(-x^3+x^2-2x+2)w=0 $$

$$\frac{dw}{dx}+\frac{(-x^3+x^2-2x+2)}{x(x^2-x+1))}w=0 $$

$$\int \frac{dw}{w}+ \int \frac{2}{x} -1- \frac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1} dx=0 $$

$$ ln|{w}|+ ln|{x}^2| -x- ln{x^2-x+1} =c $$

$$ ln|{w}|+ ln|{x}^2|- ln{x^2-x+1} =c+x $$

$$\frac{wx^2}{x^2-x+1}=ce^x$$

Choosing c=1 as the solution to the differential equation.

$$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{e^x(x^2-x+1)}{x^2}$$

Is this right?

Comment: $$\dfrac{-x^3+x^2-2 x+2}{x \left(x^2-x+1\right)} = \dfrac{1-2 x}{x^2-x+1}+\dfrac{2}{x}-1$$

Comment: Yes I got the same result too.. Use this as an integrating factor and solve the differential equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given

$$\tag 1 (x^2-x+1) y'' - (x^2 + x) y' + (x+1) y = 0$$

You made a good Reduction of Order substitution using $y = v x \implies y' = v + v' x$ and we reduce $(1)$ to

$$\tag 2 x(x^2-x+1)\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}+(-x^3+x^2-2x+2)\dfrac{dv}{dx}=0$$

Next, you correctly let $\dfrac{dv}{dx} = w$ and reducing $(2)$ we get a Separable Equation that we can integrate as

$$\tag 3 \displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{w} ~dw = \int -\dfrac{(-x^3+x^2-2x+2)}{x(x^2-x+1))}~dx = \int \left(\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1}-\dfrac{2}{x}+1\right)dx=0$$

Integrating $(3)$ results in

$$\ln w = \ln(x^2-x+1) -2 \ln x + x + c$$

Solving for $w$

$$\tag 4 w = \dfrac{c~e^x(x^2-x+1)}{x^2}$$

From the original substitution $\dfrac{dv}{dx} = w$, we now have a Separable Equation and can integrate

$$\displaystyle \int dv = \int \dfrac{c~e^x(x^2-x+1)}{x^2}~dx$$

We get

$$v(x) = c ~ e^x \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{x}\right) + k$$

We now substitute back our original $y = v x$ and have

$$y(x) = c ~ e^x(x - 1) + k x$$